# Command not running while using jupyter note in VScode

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, gpu

I am using the Jupyter notebook supported in VScode to develop an image classification model.

The problem is that commands that work well in Colab or jupyter do not work well in Jupyter notebooks on VScode.

As you can see in the picture below,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dls9n.png)
When the training command is run in Colab, it operates for about 10 minutes.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Y2yR.png)
However, in Jupyter notebook on VScode, after running for about 8.6 seconds on my server, it is checked as if it was working normally and then completed.

At this time, the usage was observed through nvidia-smi. In the case of CPU, the usage goes up to 135% and then decreases at the completion stage, which is 8.6 seconds later. The GPU doesn't seem to work at all.

What I'm wondering here is,

1. Is the problem with Jupyter notebook in VScode (because it works normally in colab)
2. Or is it a problem with my server's GPU settings for deep learning (because I don't use the GPU, it only uses the CPU and then turns off)

If you are an expert, please help

My server spec :

- GPU (NVIDIA Corporation GA106 [GeForce RTX 3060], rev a1)
- NVIDIA (495.44)
- CUDA (11.2)
- cuDNN (8.1.1)
- Ubuntu (Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS)
- tensorflow (2.6.2)

The command was referenced from the site :
https://learnopencv.com/classification-with-localization/

Comment: I'm a developer on the Jupyter extension. I would expect that VS Code Jupyter would have the same results as running in Jupyter notebook or Colab. First question is it possible that you are not running the code in the same kernel? You'd want to make sure that you are using the exact same environment in both Colab and in VS Code.

Comment: Hi! Could you try again by using tf.device() for mandating GPU usage before training?https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu,